How to resize an SVG without also resizing the background
I want to use SVG as logo of my website.
I tried to resize it by modifying its width and height, but it doesn't work, because it resizes the whole image.
I also tried these solutions:

Resizing SVG in HTML?
How to resize an svg?
How does one make a SVG background that stretches rather than tiles?

This is what I want:

import React from 'react';
import "./Header.css";
import IconSvg from "../../../assests/logo.svg";
// import SvgImage from "../../../utils/logo";
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="header-img">
        {/* <img src={IconSvg} alt="icon"/> */}
        {/* <SvgImage/> */}
      </div>
      <div className="header-controlls">
        <div className="header-controlls-controll">
          <NavLink className={"link"} to="/"> Home </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div className="header-controlls-controll">
          <NavLink className={"link"} to="/About">About </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div className="header-controlls-controll">
          <NavLink className={"link"} to="/Orders">Orders </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div className="header-controlls-controll">
          <NavLink className={"link"} to="/Cart">Cart </NavLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

I tried to import the SVG directly, and through a React component, but none of them work, and resizing the image decreases the entire image size, which is not beneficial for me.
I tried stting up the preserveAspectRatio, viewBoxheight, and width, but none of them work as per my need.

Please check if your logo SVG has a "tight" appropriate viewBox so it doesn't introduce undesired padding/space around the artwork.

I tried that one too but it also changed the background btw I created the other SVG file according to need it worked.  Thanks

Try importing the SVG as a React component:
import { ReactComponent as Arrow } from "./assets/arrow.svg";

<Arrow width={50} height={50} />

